# Dragging & dropping a PictureBox into another

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Hi I'm new to Visual Basic and have a few questions.

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 (visual Basic).

As an exercise I'm attempting to create a paint mixer program. The interface will consist of a colour wheel made up of 12 circular colours and a mixing machine. (the wheel is similar to the image below, mixing machine not shown)

[image: colour wheel](![enter image description here]

The child will be able to drag and drop a 2 colours into a mixing machine to produce the resulting colour which will then appear on the wheel enabling them to produce further colours and so on etc.

I thought I would use PictureBoxes for the paint pots and mixing machine. This would allow me to attach a visual image to the component with a transparent background etc which would look OK.

1) Are these components suitable the this purpose?

I have produced the following code which enables me to drag 2 picture boxes around the screen.

```
    Dim point As New System.Drawing.Point
    Dim X, Y As Integer

    Private Sub Box2_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles P2.MouseDown
    X = Control.MousePosition.X - P2.Location.X
    Y = Control.MousePosition.Y - P2.Location.Y
End Sub

Private Sub Box2_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles P2.MouseMove
    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
        point = Control.MousePosition
        point.X = point.X - (X)
        point.Y = point.Y - (Y)
        P2.Location = point
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Box1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles P1.MouseDown
    X = Control.MousePosition.X - P1.Location.X
    Y = Control.MousePosition.Y - P1.Location.Y
End Sub

Private Sub Box1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles P1.MouseMove
    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
        point = Control.MousePosition
        point.X = point.X - (X)
        point.Y = point.Y - (Y)
        P1.Location = point
    End If
End Sub
```

I will need to arrange the PictureBoxes in a circle with only the red, green and blue visible at the start of the game.

2) How would I do this so that if the screen changes they stay in the relative position or should I have a fixed screen size?

The boxes would also need to be fixed to the position, EG if the child drags the box to a position on the screen and releases the mouse button the pot returns to the same spot.

3) How would I code this?
   I assume I would need the X & Y to fix the position.

If the child releases the pot onto the mixing machine and adds another colour pot on the machine then the resulting colour pot will appear on the wheel.

4) How would I code this?
   I assume I would also need the X & Y coordinates to check if it's over the PictureBox (colour mixing machine) or is there an event such as OnDragOver to deal with this.

I will eventually add sound to the app at a later date, EG (speech) 'You have mixed red and blue to produce purple' etc...if this is possible?

I have a good understanding of OOP in Java and am attempting to try something new!

All suggestion, commenst and help welcome to get me kick started in the right direction and appreciated.

Regards

J

Comment: For the start you probably should fix the screen size to make it easier. You could then define rectangles on the screen and check which rectangle the dragged picturebox is released in and then act accordingly. You have e.g. one rectangle for each color spot and for the mixing machine. You also define locations where the pots should be placed for each rectangle. Stuff to look at that may come in handy for this are dictionaries to quickly find properties for rectangles, delegates for handlers.

Comment: Using a PictureBox isn't exactly ideal, the proper way to do it is layering paint.  In other words, Graphics.DrawImage() calls for each "pot" you drop.  It can be made to work, you have to change the Parent property of the picture box to the bottom one.  But overlapping them will not work correctly.

Comment: @ Hans, thanks - would you please elaborate further for me?